# Any ideas how to allow CSS input to perfectly work in the text area with wp_kses?

Tags: wp-kses

I'm having issues with wp_kses. I have a text area that allows CSS input (only) While the rest of the CSS gets through (don't have any issues ever since). Until one user , inputs a CSS Code like this one:

```
li > mycolor { color: blue; }
```

It will be rendered like this (after passing through the filter):

```
li &gt; mycolor { color: blue; }
```

The greater sign is passed through entities. Any ideas how to make this work while still having the filter?

Comment: Why do you think this is `wp_kses`? Are _you_ using `wp_kses` somewhere? Have you traced this to `wp_kses` somewhere in the Core?

Answer (score 0):

The > entity is probably being filtered by "esc_textarea". You can read more about "esc_" below:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation